# Flipping one textured face of an object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, compositing-nodes

I came up with a problem of **flipping only one face of the texture horizontally** on flags as shown below in the image. What I want to do is to make one (front) face of the flag stay as it is now, but I would like to flip the other (rear face) **by 180 degrees**. I tried playing with the scale factors in the mapping node, rotating that face etc. The problem is that I am aware of the potential solution to this problem by duplicating the face and flipping the normals, but it will just make my job a lot harder due to complexity of the model and a huge lag I am currently experiencing. I would have to repeat the process a lot of times too. Therefore I would like to do it via **compositor**. I made a composition as shown on the screenshot, but it doesn't work no matter how I make them and what factors I put in. Can anyone take a look at it please, and tell me if I am doing something wrong, or it just isn't possible to be achieved in this way.

[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Try to change the coordinates to UV and unwrap the flag

Comment: Tried it now, the texture just rotates 90 degrees. No matter what I do next or what inputs I apply, nothing happens. But thanks alot for the tip.

Comment: you're using 'normal' as the vector input. you should be using 'uv' instead, otherwise what you do in the uv editor makes no difference

Comment: I tried, it doesn't make any difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UV coordinates instead of normal.  Then unwrap the flag with  **<kbd>u</kbd> > unwrap**.  Then in the UV image editor, while still in edit mode, scale the UV map along the horizontal axis by -1:  **<kbd>s</kbd> > <kbd>x</kbd> > <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>**.  Scaling by -1 should flip the image.

Update:  Misunderstood the question.  I modified your node setup. This should make an un-flipped image appear on the back of the face.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it still doesn't give me the results I want. In this way it flips texture on both sides of the face, and I need it only in one side (so that it looks correctly from both ways you look). And even if it worked I would have had to repeat this process 24 times, and it isn't quite convenient, so I'm trying to do it just via compositor. But thanks for your help I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Modified your node setup, but you beat me to it.  Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Hahaha thanks a lot for your effort and help. I honestly appreciate the time you took for it. I wish you all the best. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems like I found a solution to my problem. The issue was with the image itself because there was only **one Image Texture** within the object, and it couldn't be flipped just via **Diffuse Node**. I just had to copy the **sourced Image Texture**, and than put UV vectors to it and scale it via X axis to -1 as suggested, and only than put it trough **Mix Shaders** and **Diffuse Nodes**. Here is the solution in the compositor. Now the flag texture looks correct in both ways, and not flipped on only one side.

[image]

Thanks to everyone for the help and answers, I appreciate it.